# Scala sbt: Multiple dependencies in sbt

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, configure

I am a new user to Scala, following the way to create a scala sbt project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ok7gYD1VbNw

---

After adding

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
```

to **build.sbt**, and refreshed the project, I got this msg.

> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
>
> [warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:(2.11.2, 2.11.7)
>
> [warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.2, 1.0.4)

And in **build.sbt**, thw word '**scalatest**' is red that means it's an unsolved dependencies.

Should I change something in Project Setting, like scala sdk?

Best Regard!

Comment: as soon as it's warining it should not be a problem. check for `error`s. If there are any - print them here.

Comment: If you use IntellJ Idea, anything can be red in `build.sbt`, but it still will compile. IDE's parser sometimes cannot parse stuff (scala code as well), so usually you can just ignore red stuff as long as it compiles. The same probably is true for other IDEs.

Comment: @Archeg If my configure is right, I can run the test file, right? At the moment, I even can't have the 'run' in IDE while right-click the file.

Comment: You've posted just a warning, which probably has nothing to do with not-workable state. What does it say when you try to run it?

Answer (score 25):

You could regard adding those dependencies:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.7",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.4"
)
```

It forces compiler to choose concrete version of libraries. It solves problem for me.

Comment: I wonder why Idea cannot figure it out itself with `scalaVersion := "2.11.7"` in `build.sbt`

Comment: This works most of the time however I'm having problem with versions `1.0.4` and `1.0.5` of `org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml`. I've gone as far as clearing them from Ivy cache but with no positive outcome.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to resolve this by excluding these from the `scalatest` dependency.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "2.2.4" % "test"
    exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-reflect")
    exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml_2.11")
)
```

Comment: I prefer this to what is stated in Bartłomiej Szałach's answer.