# How to force Scala to use a different library version?

Tags: scala, sbt

After adding

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
```

to **build.sbt**, and refreshed the project, I got this msg.

> SBT project import
>
> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but
>   different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
>
> [warn]  * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.5, 1.0.4)

[Changing the above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39332023/4533188) to

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
  exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-reflect")
  exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml_2.11")
)
```

solves the issue. However, instead of excluding scala-xml_2.11 version 1.0.5 from scalatest, I would like to [force the scala compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570734/4533188) to use scala-xml_2.11 version 1.0.5 instead of version 1.0.4. (I researched the versions at https://mvnrepository.com.) Thus I tried substituting `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"` for

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % "2.11.8",
  "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.5"
)
```

This however results in

> SBT project import
>
> [warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency
>   org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8
>
> [warn]    in default#myproject$sources_javadoc_2.10;1.0 differs
>   from Scala binary version in project (2.10).
>
> [warn] Binary version (2.11) for dependency
>   org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.8
>
> [warn]    in default#myproject$sources_javadoc_2.10;1.0 differs
>   from Scala binary version in project (2.10).
>
> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but
>   different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version:
>
> [warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-library:(2.11.8, 2.10.4)
>
> [warn]  * org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:(2.11.8, 2.10.4)
>
> [warn]    [FAILED     ]
>   com.artima.supersafe#supersafe_2.10.4;1.1.0!supersafe_2.10.4.jar(src):
>   (0ms)
>
> [warn] ==== local: tried
>
> [warn]
>   /home/user/.ivy2/local/com.artima.supersafe/supersafe_2.10.4/1.1.0/srcs/supersafe_2.10.4-sources.jar
>
> [warn] ==== activator-local: tried [warn]  /Development/Activator/activator-dist-1.3.10/repository/com.artima.supersafe/supersafe_2.1...
>   (show balloon)

What am I supposed to do?

## Edit: What else I tried and did not work:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5"
)

// ScalaTest
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
```

> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but
>   different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: [warn] *
>   org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.5, 1.0.4)

---

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml_2.11" % "1.0.5"
)

// ScalaTest
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
```

> Error:Error while importing SBT project:
> ...
>
> ```
> [info]
> Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.8 ... [info] Resolving
> org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.8 ... [trace] Stack trace
> suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output. [trace] Stack
> trace suppressed: run 'last :ssExtractDependencies' for the full
> output. [error] (:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved
> dependency: org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11_2.11;1.0.5: not
> found [error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException:
> unresolved dependency:
> org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.11_2.11;1.0.5: not found [error]
> Total time: 4 s, completed 01.10.2016 17:46:55
> ```

---

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5"
)

// ScalaTest
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
  exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-reflect")
  exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml")
)
```

> [warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but
>   different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: [warn] *
>   org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.5, 1.0.4)

## My `build.sbt`

```
name := "MyProject"
version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5"
)

// ScalaTest
//libraryDependencies += "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.0"
//libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.0" % "test"
  exclude("org.scala-lang", "scala-reflect")
  exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml_2.11")
)
```

Answer (score 3):

The way to exclude specific transitive dependency is this:

1. Run `sbt evicted` to figure out which of the project dependencies is pulling in outdated library, let's assume the problematic library is: `com.typesafe.slick`.
2. Add the following exclude (the parentheses are important):

   `("com.typesafe" %% "slick" % "3.1.1").exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", "scala-xml_2.11")`

   Add this normally as you would be listing dependencies.
3. This will prevent sbt from including any version of `scala-xml` that was coming in as a transitive dependency of Slick.

Answer (score 0):

Don't substitute; you need both `scalaVersion` and `libraryDependencies`. 
Though use

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value,
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.5"
)
```

to avoid bugs when you eventually change `scalaVersion`.

By removing `scalaVersion` you get default `scalaVersion := "2.10.4"` (with your version/settings of SBT, at least) but your `libraryDependencies` still require 2.11.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `"scala-xml_2.11"?

Comment: This did not work in any case (see updated question).

Comment: 1. Note the difference between `%%` and `%`. `%%` adds the correct Scala version suffix (`_2.11` or `_2.10`) automatically.

Comment: 2. To get rid of the warning, you may need to find the dependency which uses scala-xml 1.0.4 and add the `exclude` to it instead of Scalatest.

Comment: 1. Ah, I did not know that. 2. scalatest has the dependence to scala-xml 1.0.5, while my scala 2.11.8 has a scala-xml 1.0.4. I thought I would just change scala's dependency to scala-xml 1.0.5 and then this would be the same as scalatest's. It seems that scala-xml can only be loaded once and not be both scala and scala-xml. Is that right? (Still that does not work, as seen in the question. I show my entire `build.sbt` - there isn't anything anymore except `name := ...` and `version := ...`.)

Comment: Scala doesn't depend on `scala-xml` at all. You must have some other dependency which depends on `scala-xml`.

Comment: Like what? Please find my `build.sbt` in the question.

Comment: 1. What is SBT version? If it's 0.13.8, you may be running into https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1933 (even in that case it's strange). 2. Do you get the warning when you do `sbt "; clean; update"` from the command line? If no, this is just an IDEA bug.

Comment: Running `sbt "; clean; update"` does not return an error. Running `sbt --about` returns `This is sbt 0.13.8`. How to check what SBT is used by my IntelliJ, I do not know. How do I check? What's the problem?